# AngularJS element.bind('resize') not updating $scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to set a scope variable for the innerWidth of the browser window using the code below.  It works when viewed in the console, but the function is not updating the $scope variable.  Why?

```
angular.element($window).bind('resize', function () {
    console.log('resize', $window.innerWidth);  // I can see change here
    $scope.window_width = $window.innnerWidth;  // no change here
});
```

Comment: What does `console.log($scope.window_width)` say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're binding something with jQlite which lives outside Angular, so you manually have to invoke a `$digest` cycle here, otherwise Angular doens't know that there are changes.

```
angular.element($window).bind('resize', function () {
    console.log('resize', $window.innerWidth);  
    $scope.window_width = $window.innerWidth; 
    $scope.$evalAsync(); 
});
```

`$scope.$evalAsync()` will call a digest cycle with a greater chance of firing inside the same js event tick then `$timeout` (more info [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2605-scope-evalasync-vs-timeout-in-angularjs.htm))

Comment: This is wrong. You don't need to apply when updating a scope variable

Comment: You have to when you're doing it from jQuery/jQLite

Comment: No such function as Async()

Comment: No you don't. He is simply updating the $scope variable. It is immediately available in the scope. You might need to apply it only if you have to invoke watch functions.

Comment: @MFB my bad, should be `$evalAsync()`

Comment: @CharlieH The reason he's not seeing the changes is because even though the scope value is updated no `$digest` has run and his UI hasn't updated, so yes, you have to call a `$digest`. Don't downvote a whole thread without giving any constructive feedback

Comment: $evalAsync() is now a valid function, but all that is happening is the $scope.window_width is becoming undefined

Comment: @MartijnWelker You must communicate with the OP via comments to ascertain if he don't see it in his view. He mentions the console. How do you know if he don't see an update in the console for ` $scope.window_width` too? I down voted the answers which had this error. And upvoted the one which detected the typo in his program.

Answer (score 3):

you have done a silly mistake may be it when you typing the question.

```
 $scope.window_width = $window.innnerWidth; //innnerWidth should be innerWidth
```

and after you update the scope variable you need to run the digest cycle manually by calling `$scope.$digest();` because resize is something happens outside of angular so we have to tell the angular to there is something to update in the scope.

what else we can use instead of `$digest()`?

1. you can wrapped the code in `$timeout` it will trigger the digest cycle it self

   `$timeout(function() {
     $scope.window_width = $window.innerWidth;
   });`
2. use `$scope.$apply();` like

   `$scope.window_width = $window.innerWidth;
   $scope.$apply();`

here is a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/KF0kfAviMOKykM0q4QpW?p=preview)

Comment: oh my god... I am so embarrassed

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
$scope.$apply(function() { $scope.window_width = $window.innnerWidth; })
```

You bind a dom event, so must force an angular digest phase

Comment: This is wrong. You don't need to apply when updating a scope variable

Comment: Read angular documentation... He bind to an event outside a digest phase. To angular detect change you must call a digest phase

Comment: I'm putting this inside the bind function, right?  Doesn't seem to work